# Javascript recursive sudoku solver

Tags: javascript, recursion, sudoku

```js
const puzzle1 = [[0,0,0,2,6,0,7,0,1],
                [ 6,8,0,0,7,0,0,9,0],
                [ 1,9,0,0,0,4,5,0,0],
                [ 8,2,0,1,0,0,0,4,0],
                [ 0,0,4,6,0,2,9,0,0],
                [ 0,5,0,0,0,3,0,2,8],
                [ 0,0,9,3,0,0,0,7,4],
                [ 0,4,0,0,5,0,0,3,6],
                [ 7,0,3,0,1,8,0,0,0]];

const puzzle2 = [[5,8,1,6,7,2,4,3,9],
                [ 7,9,2,8,4,3,6,5,1],
                [ 3,6,4,5,9,1,7,8,2],
                [ 4,3,8,9,5,7,2,1,6],
                [ 2,5,6,1,8,4,9,7,3],
                [ 1,7,9,3,2,6,8,4,5],
                [ 8,4,5,2,1,9,3,6,7],
                [ 9,1,3,7,6,8,5,2,4],
                [ 6,2,7,4,3,5,1,0,0]]; // 6,2,7,4,3,5,1,9,8

var dummy;
dummy = puzzle2;

function poss(x,y,n) {
    for(let i=0;i<dummy.length;i++) {
        if (dummy[x][i] === n) { return false}
        if (dummy[i][y] === n) { return false}
    }

    // find the group start for x and y
    groupSize = Math.sqrt(dummy.length);
    yStart = Math.floor(y/groupSize);
    xStart = Math.floor(x/groupSize);

    // check numbers in the gridgroup
    for (let i=0;i<groupSize;i++) {
        for (let j=0;j<groupSize;j++) {
            if (dummy[i + yStart*groupSize][j + xStart*groupSize] === n) { return false}
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function Solve() {
    for(let y=0;y<dummy.length;y++) {
        for(let x=0;x<dummy.length;x++) {
            if (dummy[y][x] === 0) {
                for (let n=1;n<10;n++) {
                    if (poss(y,x,n)) {
                        dummy[y][x] = n;
                        Solve();
                        dummy[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(dummy);
}
```

I'm pretty sure with this logic the problem can be solved but I can't seem to express it in code. I've encountered two problems so far,

1. when running puzzle 1 it changes the first 0 (top-left) to 3 and the returns 'undefined'.
2. it solves puzzle 2 correctly, but throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '9' of undefined
    at Solve (script.js:57)
    at Solve (script.js:56)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

this happens because both x & y = 9, which they shouldn't as the for loop for both should only run while x (or y) < dummy.length (9).

The logic is from a python based video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM&t=394s

**EDIT**

The second problem is resolved now, but it returns a non-solved puzzle now. As in it's the exact same as the base puzzle. When using the debugger on chrome I've been clicking through the whole process and it actually completely solves the puzzle, but then it resets everything to 0 even though it was all correct.

Comment: I would recommend using `for (var x =` and `for (var y=` ... the way you've  written it, x, y, (and i) are globals - so after Solve calls Solve the values of x and/or y would not be the same as before Solve calls Solve, and could easily be 9

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you!, that solved problem 2 at least, but right now I'm experiencing a somewhat new problem, I'll update my question in a sec.